# Como aplicar un DISTINCT condicional entre 2 columnas?

Tags: sql, count, distinct

Actualmente estoy trabajando con una tabla que tiene un aspecto similar a la siguiente...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de ella encontramos 3 columnas, el id, folio y gasto.
Me interesa saber como puedo contar todos los id cuyo folio sea distinto. Se que puedo contar todos los id con la sintaxis:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM table.1
```

Y que también puedo contar los id distintos si aplico

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id))
FROM table.1
```

Pero ambos resultados no me eliminan la información repetida de folio. El problema es que algunos id tienen solo 2 folios, otros 1 y así, por lo cual no puedo simplemente contar los id y multiplicarlos por el numero de máximo de folios.

Algunas de las sintaxis que se me ocurrieron fueron:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id, folio)
FROM table.1
```

sintaxis 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), DISTINCT(Folio)
FROM table.1
```

sintaxis 3:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM table.1
GROUP BY id, folio
```

Nota: Cabe decir que tampoco busco eliminar valores repetidos, ya que puede ser que tenga el mismo id, mismo folio, pero diferente gasto; solo busco contar el numero total de folios cuyos id sea diferente.

Comment: Para validar, en tu ejemplo que debería retornar?? 9 ???

Comment: Asi es, los folios que pusé en amarillo los contaria como 1 solo valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con 2 select resulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(c) from(
SELECT COUNT(folio) as c
FROM tabla
GROUP BY id,folio)
```

Para sumar las columnas gastos:

SELECT id, folio, sum(gasto) as gasto
FROM tabla
GROUP BY id,folio

Aquí no tiene sentido realizar una segunda agrupación, ya que de hacerlo no verías el detalle. Solo tendría sentido si quisieras ver el total de TODO cuyo valor es de 2540

Comment: Y en casi de que me interesa sumar las columnas de gastos con los 2 folios iguales, podria agregar: SELECT c, SUM(gasto) FROM(SELECT folio as c FROM tabla GROUP BY id, folio, gasto? Muchas gracias, por cierto.

Comment: @AlexisSM Edite la respuesta, para responderte esto último

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la respuesta más simple es con un sub select, algo así como:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(Select distinct id, folio from table.1)
```

Dependiendo el motor de base de datos que estes usando cambia un poco la sintaxis de un subquery, por ejemplo en Microsoft SQL Server le tenes que dar un alias al subquery, te queda así:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(Select distinct id, folio from table.1) A
```

Donde A es un alias que le das al subquery, en este caso para que no tire error. Desconozco si hay alguna forma mas simple, pero el subquery resulta muy cómodo para situaciones complejas